# ember.js how to display different filtered lists for a view? complex setup

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I have a an app where i have a car view and i have a list of countries with a checkbox against each that when i check a country it displays a view below with a list of parts available in that country.

Checking more countries displays the parts in more countries down the page.

The parts are all stored in one place but need to be filtered by coutry field to just display parts in that section for that country.

I can create the list of countries and when checked it displays a country section below with the parts list in it but how do i filter to only display for that country.   Do i need to create views for each country and a controller for each countries parts to display ??

Surely there is a better way.

EDIT :

This is how i need the page to be displayed :

```
Coutries : UK <- selected

           USA

           China <- selected


Parts available in UK:

....

Parts available in China

....
```

So i need seperate lists displayed ofr each country selected.

Please help
Rick

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This would probably be best solved using nested views. You can see [my jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/XmzzS/).

I don't think it's a terribly complicated approach, but if you have any questions about the design please let me know.

Handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{#each App.countriesController}}
        {{view Ember.Checkbox titleBinding="name" valueBinding="isChecked"}}
    {{/each}}
    <hr />
    {{#each App.countriesController}}
    {{#if isChecked}}
        {{view App.PartsByCountryView contentBinding="this" partsListBinding="App.partsController"}} <br />      
    {{/if}}
{{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="selected-country">
    Country: {{content.name}} <br />
    Parts:
    {{#each filteredParts}}
        {{name}}
    {{/each}}
</script>
​
```

App Code:

```
window.App = App = Ember.Application.create();
/**************************
* Models
**************************/
App.Country = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: "",
    isChecked: null
});

App.Part = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    name: "",
    countryId: null
});

/**************************
* Views
**************************/
App.PartsByCountryView = Ember.View.extend({
    content: null,
    partsList: null,
    templateName: 'selected-country',

    filteredParts: function() {
        return this.get("partsList").filterProperty('countryId', this.getPath('content.id'))
    }.property('partsList.@each').cacheable() 
});

/**************************
* Controllers
**************************/
App.set('countriesController', Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: Ember.A()
}));

App.set('partsController', Ember.ArrayController.create({
    content: Ember.A()
}));

/**************************
* App Logic
**************************/
$(function() {
    App.get('countriesController').pushObjects([
        App.Country.create({id: 1, name: "USA"}),
        App.Country.create({id: 2, name: "UK"}),
        App.Country.create({id: 3, name: "FR"})
    ]);

    App.get('partsController').pushObjects([
        App.Part.create({id: 1, name: "part1", countryId: 1}),
        App.Part.create({id: 2, name: "part2", countryId: 1}),
        App.Part.create({id: 3, name: "part3", countryId: 1}),
        App.Part.create({id: 4, name: "part4", countryId: 2}),
        App.Part.create({id: 5, name: "part5", countryId: 2}),
        App.Part.create({id: 6, name: "part6", countryId: 2}),
        App.Part.create({id: 7, name: "part7", countryId: 2}),
        App.Part.create({id: 8, name: "part8", countryId: 3}),
        App.Part.create({id: 9, name: "part9", countryId: 3}),
        App.Part.create({id: 10, name: "part10", countryId: 3}),
        App.Part.create({id: 11, name: "part11", countryId: 3})
    ]);
});
​
```

Comment: Hi Roy thanks for the great answer.  Just one question :  If i goto the console and try and add another part like this `App.get('partsController').pushObjects([
        App.Part.create({id: 999, name: "part999", countryId: 2})]);   `   How do i get it to add it to the relevent section without having to click the check box of and on again ?     Thanks alot again

Comment: Sorry I forget to add a property to watch for in my definition of the filteredParts computed property. I've updated to code and jsFiddle. Has this successfully answered your question?

Comment: wow that was very quick thank you very much and yes this has completetly answered my question.

Answer (score 2):

I would structure your application like this:

1. A model with just a list o part objects. Each object holds how many of that part exist in each country.
2. A controller that filters that list depending on countries selected.
3. A view that sets in the controller which countries are selected.
4. A view that displays a list from the controller with the selected parts.

I've done that here:

http://jsfiddle.net/NPeeQ/2/

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create();

App.model = Ember.Object.create({

    parts: Ember.ArrayProxy.create({
        content: [
        {
            name: 'wheel',
            stock: {
                uk: 3,
                fi: 2,
                se: 0
            }
        },
        {
            name: 'windscreen',
            stock: {
                uk: 0,
                fi: 1,
                se: 3
            }
        }
    ]}),

    countries: ['uk', 'fi', 'se']

});

App.partController = Ember.Object.create({

    filterBy: {},

    setFilterBy: function (country, on) {

        var filterBy = $.extend({}, this.get('filterBy'));

        if (on) {
            filterBy[country] = true;
        } else {
            delete filterBy[country];
        }

        this.set('filterBy', filterBy);

    },

    // returns all available parts filtered by filterBy.
    availableParts: function () {

        var parts = App.model.parts;

        var filter = this.filterBy;

        var arr = [];

        App.model.countries.forEach(function(c) {

            if (!filter[c]) return;

            arr.push({heading:c});

            var tmp = App.model.parts.filter(function(p) {
                return p.stock[c] && p.stock[c] > 0;
            });

            arr = arr.concat(tmp);

        });            

        return arr;

    }.property('filterBy', 'App.model.parts').cacheable()

});

App.SelectorView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'selector',

    click: function(event) {

        if (event.target.tagName !== 'INPUT')
            return;

        var clicked = $(event.target).closest('label');
        var index = this.$().find('label').index(clicked);

        var country = App.model.countries[index];
        var on = event.target.checked;

        App.partController.setFilterBy(country, on);

    }
});

App.PartsView = Ember.View.extend({
    templateName: 'parts'
});


$(function() {

    App.selectorView = App.SelectorView.create();
    App.partsView = App.PartsView.create();

    App.selectorView.append();
    App.partsView.append();

})
```

And the handlebars:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="selector">
    {{#each App.model.countries}}
    <label><input type="checkbox"/> {{this}}</label>
    {{/each}}
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="parts">

    {{#each App.partController.availableParts}}

      {{#if heading}}
        <h2>{{heading}}</h2>
      {{else}}
    {{name}} <br/>
      {{/if}}

    {{/each}}

</script>
```

Comment: Hi Martin   thanks a lot for the extensive answer.  this will solve my problem but i think it is a cleaner solution that Roy has provided.  I hope you agree. thanks

Answer (score 1):

For the parts list, you could use an `#each` helper bound to a collection on a controller. The controller could observe a controller bound to the currently selected countries. When the selection changes, it would update the collection, which would automatically update your parts list.

Comment: thanks but this would create one list that includes all parts available in the selected countries.    But i need to display these seperately.  Please see my edit above. any ideas ?